# How to resolve pop from empty list error?

Tags: python-3.x

My goal is to create a dictionary of lists something like {1: ['c','b' 'a'], 2: ['c', 'b', 'a']}

```
a_list = ['a,','b', 'c'] #some_dates
some_dict = dict([(i, []) for i in range(1, 4)]) #date_dict
a_list.reverse()
print(a_list)
for key in some_dict.keys():
    a = some_dict[key]
    while len(empty_list) < 14:
        a.append(a_list.pop())

some_dict
```

However using this code, I get the following error message. I don't understand why I'm getting the error pop from an empty list when a_list has clearly already been created at the beginning?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-90ae0d4de7b6> in <module>
      6     a = some_dict[key]
      7     while len(a) < 4:
----> 8         a.append(a_list.pop())
      9 
     10 some_dict

IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: Because it wants to keep going for some reason. Use a for loop.

Comment: Print the Len of the list before you pop and see how it gets empty

Answer (score 0):

Your code intends to pop `a_list` into your dict.

- But **your while-loop isn't checking `len(a_list)`, it's checking the wrong variable: `len(empty_list)`**, which isn't even defined! (Always recheck your code example in a clean session before posting your question here.)
- Anyway, it wouldn't even make sense for your loop's termination condition to be the check `while len(a_list) < 14:` as that won't prevent `a_list` becoming empty and you attempting to do `a_list.pop()`. You should be checking `while len(a_list) > 0`. (Assuming `len(a_list) < 14` was true the first time through the loop, pop'ping is only going to keep making `a_list` shorter, so `len(a_list) < 14` will continue to be true, even when `len(a_list) == 0`, so it won't prevent the `IndexError: pop from empty list`. That's not what you want to do.
- But we frown on this sort of iterative stuff in Python, we have **list comprehensions** and **dict comprehensions**. You can do everything you want to do in a one-line dict comprehension:

  `>>> {k: a_list for k in some_dict}
  {1: ['c', 'b', 'a,'], 2: ['c', 'b', 'a,'], 3: ['c', 'b', 'a,']}`
- That's faster, cleaner, more legible, almost impossible to write wrong. It also doesn't use up your input destructively, unlike `a_list.pop()`
- No need to declare yet another variable `a` to hold the list you're building for `some_dict[key]`. That also causes another bug, because you build your temporary `a`, but you never assign it `some_dict[key] = a` after the while-loop finished]s, before you do another iteration of the for-loop with the next key. **You're throwing away `a`.** (But anyway if you code this directly as a dict comprehension, with no temporary variable like `a`, you can't make that mistake.)